# How to create custom button in Django admin, which create many object?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model Student:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    grade= models.CharField(max_length=8, default='')

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('name','lastname','grade')

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

Imagine, that I have an additional model `Person` ( with `name` and `surname` fields). My situation is just an example.
I want to create a button in the Django admin (it's very important to implement this in Django admin page), that creates many `Student` objects at once (`name` and `lastname` we take from `Person`, with empty `grade` field, which we can fill in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Admin Actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) to do this:

First you define a `create_student` function that performs the insert activity. This will be linked to a Person Admin, since the action is performed from Persons. For example:

```
@admin.action(description='Create students from selected persons')
def create_student(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for person in queryset:
        s = Student(name = person.name, lastname=person.lastname)
        s.save()
```

so you can add the action to a `PersonAdmin`

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [create_student]

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```